# Return specific object's property value RXJS .map and .filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, rxjs

I have an array of objects, each with the same 2 parameters: `contentId` and `data`.

```
[
    {
      contentId: 12343,
      data: 'a bunch of data'
    },
    ...
]
```

My RXJS observable returns the object fine with the below code.

```
this.$bcc = this.bccService.getBcc().pipe(
  map(data => data.find(obj => obj.contentId == 12343)), // returns the matching object
  // map(data => data.find(obj => obj.contentId == 12343)['data']), // undefined
);
```

However, how could I best specify the matching object's `data` parameter value?

Comment: What is `map`? Which library are you using?

Comment: Clarified in the question that I'm using observables and the RXJS `map` operator. However, `.find` is vanilla JS.

Comment: Should you not use `filter` in the first `map` (instead of `find`)? Otherwise the second `map` will not get an array, but the object... Or change the second pipe argument to deal with the found object instead of an array..

Comment: I'm not clear on your exact issue, but have you seen `pluck`? It allows you to pull out a specific nested property. See the docs here: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pluck

Comment: @DeborahK for the win every time. Pluck appears to be the tool for this job. If you have availability could you compose an answer with usage in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Either `. syntax` or `key syntax` should be fine so you can use:

```
data.find(item => item.contentId === 12343).data;
data.find(item => item.contentId === 12343)['data'];
```

Not related I guess, but not clear why there is a `map` in the pipe?

```js
const data = [
    {
      contentId: 12343,
      data: 'a bunch of data'
    },
     {
      contentId: 45678,
      data: 'a bunch of data'
    },
]

console.log(data.find(item => item.contentId === 12343).data);
console.log(data.find(item => item.contentId === 12343)['data']);
```

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the question again, the syntax is not the issue. I see is that you are setting data property in the first map which overwrites data value. Please try as follows:

```
this.$bcc = this.bccService.getBcc().pipe(
  map(data => data.find(obj => obj.contentId == 12343)), // returns the matching object
  map(data => data.propertyInData), // at this point data is {contentId:12343,data: 'a bunch of data'
    },
);
```

Comment: Hey @chev thanks but as described in my question those return undefined. About the map, I'm mapping the selected object to the observable because I don't need the entire payload just the matching object... and trying to go even deeper to get that object's data value.

Comment: They both return undefined? Your question was how to access the property. As per your array and example above they do in fact yield the data property. It sounds like the issue is related to the `pipe` and `map`. Could you elaborate more on what lib you are using for pipe or show your own pipe implementation?

Comment: map returns a value, so not clear if that data gets passed into the next operator in your pipe statement. Can you replace the second operator with the same as the first just as a test. So they both `map(data => data.find(obj => obj.contentId == 12343))`

Comment: @BenRacicot please see the updated answer - you are overwriting the `data` value in the first `map` so the subsequent `map` must consider this.

Comment: thanks for your continued help. The first map gets the correct object I want. (The second map was really only an example of map operator that doesn't work.)  `map(data => data.propertyInData)` doesn't get the value of any `propertyInData`.